# Iterate through another Xml using Document() in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to iterate a loop which is in another xml using document($fileRefernce).

See the code

```
<xsl:for-each select="document($fileRefernce)/*//Info/element/item">                      
           {
           "@Name": "<xsl:value-of        select="document($fileRefernce)/*//Info/element/item/@Name" />" ,
        "@Quantity": "<xsl:value-of select="document($fileRefernce)/*//Info/element/item/@quantity" />"
        }<xsl:if test="$elementCount!=position()">,</xsl:if>                       
    </xsl:for-each>
```

where variable elementCount is just storing the number of Info/elemnt node present .

Using this if i iterate through the info loop then it always gives the value of first node even though it iterates second time.

and i get the output like this:

```
{
"@Name" : "xyz",
 "@Quantity": "1"
 },

 {
"@Name" : "xyz",
 "@Quantity": "1"
 },
```

Can anyone tell me how can i solve this .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is giving you the first node each time because you are selecting the first node each time...

```
<xsl:value-of select="document($fileRefernce)/*//Info/element/item/@Name" />
```

You have an absolute path here, and it is not using your current context node at all. Try simplifying the expression to use a relative path...

```
<xsl:for-each select="document($fileRefernce)/*//Info/element/item">                      
  {
    "@Name": "<xsl:value-of select="@Name" />" ,
    "@Quantity": "<xsl:value-of select="@quantity" />"
  }<xsl:if test="$elementCount!=position()">,</xsl:if>                       
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You Saved me Tim..Thanks.

I tried other ways but never thought it would be this simple !

Thanks for your effort

Comment: @hiccup: If you like this answer, it is considered polite to accept it.

Comment: @zx485 : I already did it, but as my reputations are less than 15 my vote is not publicly displayed